# Convert int value in Currency in Word Format in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

if user can enter value 1234 then output will be One thousand two hundred thirty four

how can i do this?

Comment: Just for sake of English "One thousand, two hundred and thirty-four".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help you

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/NumToWord.aspx